Symfony Process in background does not execute as expected in Drupal 9
I am implementing a custom queue worker in a Drupal 9 project. When a user visits a page, I enqueue an item and immediately trigger Drush to process the queue in the background using Symfony Process. However, the queue worker (processItem()) is not invoked when I use Process::start() for asynchronous execution.
Here’s what I’ve observed:

Using Process::start(), the process seems to start correctly (I can get a valid PID), but queue:run does not process any items, and the queue remains unchanged.
If I wait a few seconds after starting the process (sleep(5), Drush works as expected, processing the queue and removing the item.
Using synchronous execution (Process::wait()) works fine, but it blocks the page request, which I want to avoid.
As a fallback, I resorted to exec() with & for a truly asynchronous call, and it works, but it feels like a workaround.

Here is a simplified version of my code (including a couple of usleep() inserted just to make sure there are no timing issues):
$queueWorkerName = 'mymodule_service_update_worker' ;
$queue = $this->queueFactory->get($queueWorkerName) ;
$queue->createItem([ 'url' => $url]) ;
usleep(100000) ;
$drupal_root = \Drupal::root() ;
$drush_path = realpath($drupal_root . '/../vendor/bin/drush') ;
if ($drush_path && is_executable($drush_path)) {
    $process = new Process([$drush_path, 'queue:run', $queueWorkerName]) ;
    $process->start() ;
    usleep(100000) ;
    $this->log->debug('Process pid: @pid', ['@pid' => $process->getPid()]) ;
}
else
    $this->log->error("Drush not found or not executable: $drush_path") ;

I’ve checked:

PHP settings: proc_open and proc_close are enabled, and the max_execution_time is set to 0 for CLI.
Drush: Running the Drush command manually works perfectly.
Database latency: Adding a small delay (usleep(100000)) after createItem() doesn’t resolve the issue.

My questions:

Is there any specific configuration required in Symfony, PHP, or Drupal to ensure Process::start() works for background tasks?
What could cause the item to remain unprocessed when using Process::start() asynchronously?
Is there a better approach to trigger a queue worker in the background in Drupal without blocking the user request?

Thank you for your insights!
EDIT: Myabe I didn't explain my use case well. My projects calls external REST services, and the reply may take from a few seconds to 20-30 seconds; fortunately there aren't many services and many parameters, so I can the responses. I want the UI to be non blocked even when a cache entry expires, so I always use the content of the cache, even if it is expired, then I put the URL of the service to be updated in a queue, but I want to trigger the queue worker immediately – my cron jobs only run at night, and it seems an overkill to run them every minute only to trigger a queue worker. So, I need to trigger a queue worker on a user request without blocking the user request itself. I found a way to do it, but it's ugly:
$command = escapeshellcmd("$drush_path queue:run $queueWorkerName");
exec($command . ' > /dev/null 2>&1 &');

Can it be done in a more elegant way?

Yes, this is expected. When the main web request process terminates it also kills the sub-process. The Drupal queue system is supposed to be triggered by the web server OS independently of web requests, usually in a cronjob.

Thank you 4uk4, so calling exec on drush, like I did, is the only way to start a long term job triggered by a web request?

You trigger queue workers by making a web request for https://www.example.com/cron/abcdef... (the full link is on the cron admin page).

That's what I do from the OS cron to invoke cron jobs at night; now I need to trigger a queue worker from a user web request without blocking the page. I will add my use case at the end of the question above.

You could add a second cron job to the OS cron table, running for example every 5 minutes, executing only the drush command for the queue worker.

Yes, I suppose that's the best strategy, thank you!
